# Deploying Ruby Rails App on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have scoured overstack for a solution to the issue but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Currently, I'm following the provided tutorial from Amazon

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)

Everything works if I deploy their Sample Application and I get the Welcome Screen.

However, when I want to deploy my own application follow the mentioned tutorial above and using rails to generate a scaffold project I get "502 Bad Gateway".

I followed [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) tutorial to setup an arbitrary 'blog' of sorts that demonstrates the basics of database interaction and such.

I have successfully:

1. Ran the server locally using rails server @ 0.0.0.0:3000/high_scores
2. ran rake db:migrate
3. ran bundle update
4. ran bundle install and all combination there of to install my gems (successfully on local machine)
5. ensured that git was in fact pushing my updates by SSHing into the machine (EC2 instance)

Examining my environment:

### Configuration:

Option 26 using eb init tools: Ruby 2.0.0 (passenger standalone)

Option "yes" for creating RDS database MySql

### Error/Log Files taken from "snapshot" feature

When visiting my instance and going to /high_scores I get this error message:

502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.4.5

### Production.log

I, [2014-06-18T19:07:45.310588 #4524]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateHighScores (20140618173833)
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-

-- this is the only thing in the file

### Gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'multi_json', '1.7.8'
gem 'json'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

### Snapshot Logs

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
-------------------------------------
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

App 31927 stdout: 
App 31927 stdout: 
[ 2014-06-18 20:38:57.0761 31847/7f322494e700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:883 ]: Could not spawn process for group /var/app/current#default: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::handleErrorResponse(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:455)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:566)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:752)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:804)

[ 2014-06-18 20:38:57.0764 31847/7f3222643700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2210 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session.
Error page:
database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:184:in `spec'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:111:in `<class:PredicateBuilder>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `eager_load!'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record.rb:155:in `eager_load!'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/2.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.41/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


/var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log
-------------------------------------
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.1
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.1
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.2.0
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.1
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.7.8
Using jbuilder 2.1.1
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using mysql2 0.3.16
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using rails 4.1.1
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.1
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups test and development were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
+ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
+ echo 'bundle install succeeded'
bundle install succeeded
+ '[' -f Gemfile.lock ']'
+ echo 'encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions'
encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions
+ chown webapp:webapp Gemfile.lock
+ '[' '' = 1 ']'
+ true

2014-06-18 20:41:08,496 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-06-18 20:41:08,496 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh
2014-06-18 20:41:15,728 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: running 'rake assets:precompile'...
I, [2014-06-18T20:41:15.568942 #32080]  INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-10faafa06109fa14582542ac1852f5c5.js
I, [2014-06-18T20:41:15.633955 #32080]  INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-cf0b4d12cded06d61176668723302161.css
Asset compilation succesful

2014-06-18 20:41:15,729 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-06-18 20:41:15,729 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh
2014-06-18 20:41:18,817 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: == 20140618173833 CreateHighScores: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:high_scores)
   -> 0.1183s
== 20140618173833 CreateHighScores: migrated (0.1184s) ========================


2014-06-18 20:41:18,817 [INFO] (32051 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-06-18 20:41:18,954 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/
2014-06-18 20:41:18,955 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01_flip.sh
2014-06-18 20:41:19,006 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
+ rm -rf /var/app/current.old
+ mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
+ mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
+ su -c 'mkdir -p /var/app/current/{tmp,public}' webapp
+ rm -rf /var/app/current.old

2014-06-18 20:41:19,006 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-06-18 20:41:19,007 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/09clean.sh
2014-06-18 20:41:19,021 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: 
2014-06-18 20:41:19,021 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Script succeeded.
2014-06-18 20:41:19,021 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/99_reload_app_server.sh
2014-06-18 20:41:19,532 [INFO] (32096 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: =============== Phusion Passenger Standalone web server started ===============
PID file: /var/app/support/pids/passenger.pid
Log file: /var/app/support/logs/passenger.log
Environment: production
Accessible via: http://0.0.0.0/

Serving in the background as a daemon.
Problems? Check http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#troubleshooting
===============================================================================
```

Notice the last section where it successfully migrates the items over.

### Questions:

1. what am I doing wrong when deploying the application?
2. I can reach my self-created index.html page just fine but I cannot reach my 'get' url endpoints generated by rails
3. Is there some configuration I missed?

Comment: after finally finding the passenger.log files I added the secret_key to environment variables to solve one problem.  This eliminates the errors I saw on the passenger.log files of the missing secret key.  please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935113/rails-4-1-aws-beanstalk-cannot-find-secret-key-base) solution.

Comment: Furthermore, even if you use scaffolds to build your ruby rails temp app it doesn't correctly place the routes in the routes.rb file.  I added get 'high_scores' => 'high_scores#view' and it finally loaded the page.  I'm new to ruby, rails, and passenger so the described problems above could be my lack of knowledge of the system.  however without adding this to routes file on my local machine running rails server, it works fine.  which leads me to believe passenger requires you to define these routes in order to work.